# MAPLE: Take the positive solution and plotting

Tags: plot, maple

I have these four equations:

```
eq1:= 1.6*10^(-7)*R*sin(t)-4.4*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-1.6*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)^2+4.2*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+2.1*10^(-9)*R*cos(t)=0;

eq2 := 8.3*10^(-8)*R*sin(t)-1.2*10^(-13)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2.9*10^(-44)*R^2*cos(t)^2+7.1*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+8.3*10^(-8)*R*cos(t)=0;

eq3 := 8.3*10^(-8)*R*sin(t)-1.2*10^(-13)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2.2*10^(-44)*R^2*cos(t)^2+7.1*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+8.3*10^(-8)*R*cos(t)=0;

eq4 := 2.1*10^(-9)*R*sin(t)-4.4*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)+1.6*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)^2+2.6*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+1.6*10^(-7)*R*cos(t)=0;
```

1. I want to solve each equation for `R`, each obviously yielding two roots and I'm always assured that one root is above the horizontal axis while the other is below it, and pick only the four non-negative roots without doing it manually i.e. for instance, write something like `res:=solve(eq1,R)`, plotting each one as a function of `t` and only then taking the positive root. I want the code to do it.
2. After obtaining the positive roots, say `{r1,r2,r3,r4}`, I want to plot on the same figure, the following 4 graphs

   plot([r1*cos(t),r1*sin(t),t=0..2*Pi]);

   plot([r2*cos(t),r2*sin(t),t=0..2*Pi]);

   plot([r3*cos(t),r3*sin(t),t=0..2*Pi]);

   plot([r4*cos(t),r4*sin(t),t=0..2*Pi]);
3. Finally, I need to outline the intersection area with some color and shade it.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this, please???

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to pick the positive root and how to iterate through your equations. From here I think you should be able to make the plots yourself. Just beware that your roots are "heavy" expressions.

```
restart:
with(plots):

# Number of equations
n := 4;

# Empty solution vector
solutions := Vector(n):

# List of equations
eq := [
       1.6*10^(-7)*R*sin(t)-4.4*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-1.6*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)^2+4.2*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+2.1*10^(-9)*R*cos(t)=0 ,
       8.3*10^(-8)*R*sin(t)-1.2*10^(-13)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2.9*10^(-44)*R^2*cos(t)^2+7.1*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+8.3*10^(-8)*R*cos(t)=0 ,
       8.3*10^(-8)*R*sin(t)-1.2*10^(-13)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2.2*10^(-44)*R^2*cos(t)^2+7.1*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+8.3*10^(-8)*R*cos(t)=0 ,
       2.1*10^(-9)*R*sin(t)-4.4*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)*sin(t)+1.6*10^(-14)*R^2*cos(t)^2+2.6*10^(-14)*R^2-1.3+1.6*10^(-7)*R*cos(t)=0 
  ]:

# Iterate through all equations
for i from 1 to n do:

    # Find and store positive root
    solutions[i] := solve(eq[i], R, useassumptions) assuming R>0:

end do:

solutions;
```